# Validate input of month/year, otherwise set it to current month/year

Tags: php, array, datetime, validation

Is there a cleaner way of doing this? I'm using `filter_input` to first check for valid input, then using it again to assign the variable. Also, my condition in `if`/`else` seems quite long.

```
$optionsMonth = array('options'=>array('min_range'=>1, 'max_range'=>12));
$optionsYear = array('options'=>array('min_range'=>1900, 'max_range'=>9999));

if ((filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'month', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $optionsMonth))&&(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'year', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $optionsYear))){
    $month = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'month', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $optionsMonth );
    $year = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'year', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $optionsYear);
} else {
    $datetime = new Datetime('NOW');
    $month = $datetime->format('m');
    $year = $datetime->format('Y');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be over thinking it.  It's actually very simple.

The only ambiguous thing is if the year is two digits.  In most cases a two digit year can be fixed like this.  I believe in your use the month and year will be all be future and nothing from the 1900s.

```
if (intval($optionsYear) < 100){$optionsYear  = '20' . $optionsYear;}
```

Then to finish up:

```
$date = strtotime("$optionsYear-$optionsMonth-13"); // yyyy-mm-dd
if ($date){  // test validity, will be false if invalid
  $month = date('m',$date);  // invalid, use today's month and year.
  $year = date('Y',$date); 
}
else{
  $month = date('m');  // valid numbers entered
  $year = date('Y'); 
}
```

Because the day of the month is no an issue I used 13.  Not that it would but in dates the month and day can cause problems.  By using a day of 13 it cannot be confused with a month.  If a date were entered as 13/4/2015, it would not be difficult to understand 13 is a day and 4 is a month. Oct, Nov, Dec would still be ambiguous if entered as 10, 11, or 12.

Answer (score 0):

Here my proposal:

- I don't need to store in array the options rules.
- I would build in both case the DateTime Object and then use always the `->format()` method
- I would use the short syntax for array (PHP 5.4+ only) `[]` inestad of `array()`

then:

```
$month = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'month', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, ['options'=>['min_range' => 1    , 'max_range' => 12]]);
$year  = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'year' , FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, ['options'=>['min_range' => 1900 , 'max_range' => 9999]]);

$D = new DateTime();

if($month && $year) 
    $D->setDate($year,$month,1);

$month = $D->format("m");
$year  = $D->format("Y");

echo "$month-$year";
```

Unfortunately the `DateTime` object is more permissive on argument input, otherwise it could be sufficient a `try ... catch` without a `filter_input`. But it could give unexpected results. However if you want more flexibility on input, then you can think in this direction.

Answer (score -2):

Your code is actually fine may be a suggestion to break it into multiple evaluations and functions for:

1. readability, clarity
2. structure
3. testability
4. code reuse

For example,

```
if ((filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'month', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $optionsMonth)) 
    &&(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'year', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $optionsYear)))
```

can be written as a function call:

```
/**
 * This function validates the input against defined valid inputs.
 * It internally calls filter_input().
 * @param {Array} $optionsMonth - valid options
 * @param {int} $month - a user supplied input
 *
 * @return {boolan} - true if valid, false otherwise.
 */ 
function is_valid_input($optionsMonth, $month);
```

Then the implementation of the function is hidden, and the output of function is clear as it does one thing, so you may use use it like this:

```
if(!is_valid_input($optionsMonth, $month) ||
    !is_valid_input($optionsYear, $year) {
   // handle defaults
}
```

Therefore the suggested approach hides the implementation of the function, allows a clear structure flow and also allows it to be testable (ie. unit-test). Further readings on [advantages of writing in functions here](https://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/tutorials/234615/the-real-advantages-of-using-functions-correctly-and-to-the-maximum-capability-)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You're presented a alternate solution, but you haven't reviewed the code, nor have you explained why your suggestion may be better.

Comment: Thank you, it made sense that it should be rewritten for code review purposes. Apologies, and I have updated the answer. Please let me know if there is any thing else to amend. Cheers.